# Scaling AVM1Movie for using with BitmapData in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a actionscript 2 SWF that I am wanting to export into a PNG, however the fact that it is loaded as a AVM1Movie in as3 is proving quite troublesome.

When you load the as2 swf in just the normal standalone flash player, you can right click -> zoom in and it scales well since its redrawing the vector data at the size. But when i'm trying to make the Loader object (that contains the loaded as2 swf) scale, whenever i draw it to a BitmapData object, i just get the original size of the swf with blank space around it, rather then having the swf scale to the new dimensions.

My code looks like this:

```
var theFile:File = File(event.target);

var dis:DisplayObject = this.mLoader.content;
dis.width *=2;
dis.height *=2;

var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(dis.width, dis.height, true, 0x00000000);
trace("display object height and width is " + dis.width + " " + dis.height);
bd.draw(dis);

var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
stream.open(theFile, FileMode.WRITE);
stream.writeBytes(PNGEncoder.encode(bd)); // needs as3corelib
stream.close();

Alert.show("saved to " + theFile.nativePath );
```

But when I open up the resulting PNG File, I get this (red shows the transparent background):

[image: resulting image]

Is there any way to make it so that when I draw the as2 swf to BitmapData, it scales it like it would in the flash player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be able to simply use scaleX and scaleY properties instead of attempting to multiple the height and width values.

```
var dis:DisplayObject = this.mLoader.content;
//dis.width *=2;
dis.scaleX = 2;
//dis.height *=2;
dis.scaleY = 2;
```

**EDIT**
Alternatively since the above isn't working for you try to use a matrix argument for the draw call.

```
var mat:Matrix = new Matrix();
mat.scale(2,2);
bd.draw(dis,mat);
```

Comment: This seems like it would work (cause when you change scaleX or scaleY, it automatically adjusts the height/width) but it does the same thing where it adjusts the background but the actual thing i want to resize is still the same scale =/

Comment: Yes, that is the answer. In the documentation for BitmapData.draw(), it notes that the Transform of the source DisplayObject is not used, so by setting the width/height to be 2x, It was modifying the Transform's matrix to have Sy and Sx to be '2', but it wasn't using it. Calling draw with the source display object's transform.matrix worked, or you can just create a new matrix like shaunhusain does.